# PayPal Hosted Solution (iframe) - Pending Payment - But Paid

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

This is an intermittent issue, so not sure what is making it happen - but here goes.

We're using PayPal Hosted Solution - iFrame.
When some customers pay with their credit card (not express option on the iFrame) sometimes the order will get stuck at Pending Payment status.
Even though the payment is Complete (and also payment_status in returned ipn array is Completed).

Also in the Comments History, the correct Processing events are recorded.

An invoice is automatically created for the customer as well.

Sometimes a work around is to create a new Invoice and Capture Offline.
But sometimes no option is given to create a new Invoice (no Invoice button).

Any help would be really appreciated!!! No idea where to even start!

Thanks!

Comment: A little further digging has provided me with more info. The actual order STATUS does change to Processing but the STATE of the order remains PENDING_PAYMENT.

Even though an invoice has been created and paid.

Is there anyway to get magento to recognise this and automatically change the STATE to processing as per the normal process?

Comment: Sounds like it relates to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/paypal-hosted-stuck-at-payment-pending (just FYI)