# Magento redirection to paypal stuck at redirection message page

Tags: checkout, ce-1.8.1.0, paypal

I'm working with Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 with this "shopper" theme. I am having a problem with paypal integration. Specifically "paypal websites payment standard" module.

The problem is that my webshop is stucked at the redirection message page and it's not continuing to paypal. Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: check this link
Hope this will solve your issue.
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/magento-1-6-paypal-standard-is-not-taking-to-paypal-payment-page/53748#53748

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the source to this sh*t now.

**Solution1:** 
It was my store that had a different dns url. Default should be: www.webhost.com/magento. Mine was set to: magento.webhost.com

and this affected the IPN or something in paypal. You could probably solve it by:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/paypal_standard_payments_setup_with_ipn

specifically url rewriting and IPN.

**Solution2:**
Goto you domain name provider. Just forward the domain without masking and it should work. You can verify by just goin directly to your magento store without the domain that you are using to forward to your magento. Try paypal checkout and it should work.